# .htaccess redirect if certain parameters are met

Tags: apache, .htaccess

To begin, I would like to say i *barely have any knowledge* with the .htaccess file.

I was wondering if there was a way to redirect example.com to a specific directory if the url format is matched with this:

```
www.example.com/YYYY/MM/
www.example.com/2019/01/article-title
```

will bring me to the **foo** directory while any other format brings me to the **bar** directory.

I have the current code to redirect from public_html to another folder but no idea on how to make a if statement

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wp/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific rule to forward requests to such pattern looks pretty straight forward:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?(\d+/\d+/.*)$ /foo/$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /bar/$1 [END]
```

If you want to be really specific about the exact format then this might be closer:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?(\d\d\d\d/\d\d/.*)$ /foo/$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /bar/$1 [END]
```

Both variants will internally rewrite `/2019/01/article-title` to `/foo/2019/01/article-title`. I *assume* that is what you actually want to achieve. All requests to URLs *not* matching that initial rule will get rewritten to `/bar/...`.

Comment: Hi there! How do I do an if else statement in your answer? i would like to add a redirect to bar directory if foo conditions were not met [but using apache 2.2 so if and else statements dont exist yet]

Comment: I am sorry, I missed that bit. I modified the answer so that all request _not_ rewritten by the first rule are caught by the second one. You actually do not need an `else` construct, since the rules are applied one by one and the `[END]` flag stops the process if one rule matches and gets applied.